# Angularjs: Listen to model change in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to find out how I can listen to when the model is updated within an directive.

```
eventEditor.directive('myAmount',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attr['ngModel'], function (v) {
            console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + v);
          });
        } 
      } 
    }
};
```

});

The directive is called within ng-repeat as

```
<div ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
    <input my-amount ng-model="ticket.price"></input> 
</div>
```

Very happy for any help. I don't understand how the scope attribute looks like within an ng-repeat.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/mihupo/1/edit

`attrs` instead `attr`

```
app.directive('myAmount',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs['ngModel'], function (v) {
            console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + v);
          });
        } 
      } ;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try doing this

```
eventEditor.directive('myAmount',function(){
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {model: '=ngModel'},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('model', function (v) {
            console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + v);
          });
        } 
      } 
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Works but response below seems little simpler by listening to attr,ngModel.

Answer (score 3):

```
eventEditor.directive('myAmount',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    required : 'ngModel'       // Add required property 
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs,ngModelCtr) {

      ngModelCtr.$render = function(){   //  Add $render 
      // Your logic
    }

  } 
 }
 };
 });
```

1. Add a required property with ngModel, Since you are using ngModel (i mean actual angular ng-model, not the user custom ng-model attribute).
2. Then call $render function. It will execute as soon as there is a change in ngModel (change in values of $modelValue and $viewValue). 
   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$render

You can use $watch that is also correct.

Comment: This is the proper way!

Answer (score -2):

Following code works for me.

```
app.directive('myAmount',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          attrs.$observe('ngModel', function (v) {
            console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + v);
          });
        } 
      } ;
    }
);
```

Comment: Observe will only observer DOM changes, not model changes.