# AngularJS - Apply directive instantly, formating currency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, filter, directive

Ok so I have the following directive on various input elements. Some of those elements are on modals so The current method doesn't really work how I want, it should apply it right before the modal opens.

```
crtPromoDir.directive('ngFormatCurr', ['$filter', function($filter)
{
    function link(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        element.blur(function()
        {
            element.val($filter('currency')((element.val() || 0), '', 2));
        });
    };

    return {
        link: link
    };
}]);
```

So basically how can I get it to apply the filter instantly and every time it changes?

SOLUTION from mccainz:

```
crtPromoDir.directive('ngFormatCurr', ['$timeout', '$filter', function($timeout, $filter)
{
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            $timeout(function()
            {
                element.val($filter('currency')((element.val() || 0), '', 2));
            });

            element.blur(function()
            {
                element.val($filter('currency')((element.val() || 0), '', 2));
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: You must use $watch for the value.

Comment: I dont think you want to apply the filter every time it changes, would change the users input before he actually had finished typing the value.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878189/angularjs-listen-to-model-change-in-a-directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize with the filter just change your code such that the filter runs in the link function. I would not try to modify the value with the filter on every keypress/change though as that will frustrate the user.

Updated to initialize on $timeout so that filter is applied after angular compilation. Also added a keypress handler and code such that filter will apply after two seconds of a keypress. I don't recommned this but it addresses your issue of having the value filter as the user types, giving a two second delay after the users keypress before the filter will apply.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NqB12vgS3mWTTG4IliTW?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-rc.1" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller = "cntrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <input ng-model="val" ng-format-curr="" />
    <script>

      var crtPromoDir = angular.module("crtPromoDir",[]);
      var app = angular.module("cntrl",[]);

      app.controller("cntrl",function($scope){
        $scope.val = 2234;
      });

      crtPromoDir.directive('ngFormatCurr', ['$filter','$timeout', function($filter,$timeout)
      {
          function link(scope, element, attrs)
          {
              var promise;

              $timeout(function(){
                element.val($filter('currency')((element.val() || 0), '', 2));
              });


              element.keypress(function(){
                if(angular.isUndefined(promise)){
                  promise = $timeout(function(){
                    element.val($filter('currency')((element.val() || 0), '', 2));
                  },2000);
                }
                else{
                  $timeout.cancel(promise);
                  promise = undefined;
                }

              });

              element.blur(function()
              {
                element.val($filter('currency')((element.val() || 0), '', 2));
              });
          };

          return {
              link: link
          };
      }]);

      angular.bootstrap(document,["crtPromoDir","cntrl"]);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The filter is already in the link function. This doesn't work either, it doesn't apply it on load, only on blur.

Comment: I modified the code so that the initialization block runs in a timeout which allows for angular to compile the app first and then our filter gets to set the value.

Comment: Realized I had left the keypress handler in the code so I updated both the plnkr and the local script as appropriate.

Comment: Do I need the keypress handler for anything? It seems that the `$timeout` makes sure it's applied on load and `blur` makes sure it's reapplied after the user enters it. I wouldn't ant to do anything while the user is typing as it can get annoying.

Comment: I agree with you. I just added the keypress handler to demonstrate how you could approach the problem. I think blur and initialization is sufficient.